# Unable to Import persistence.xml within applicationContext.xml file

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence, javabeans, applicationcontext

I'm using eclipse juno IDE
I have Java application which have src folder. within the folder I have:

1) applicationContext.xml

2) persistence.xml

I also have DBInterface and i implemented it with JPA. 
Now in the applicationContext.xml file I have a bean for the JPA implemention.

When I tried to inject the bean i got an excpetion that said something like "No Persistence Provider was found".

So I tried to import the persistence file within the applicationContext file but i'm getting another exception.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-aop-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-context-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd/spring-spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jms-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jee-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-lang-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd/spring-spring-osgi.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-tx-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-util-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="JPA"  class="pack.jpa.JPAQueries"/>
    <import resource="persistence.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"> 
         <persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" name="MyJPA"> 
             <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
             <class>pack.bl.Travels</class>
             <class>pack.bl.Example</class> 
             <properties> <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/> 
                 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taxis"/> 
                 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/> 
                 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
                 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
             </properties> 
         </persistence-unit>
```

**mainClass**

```
public class Program {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ApplicationContext context = new  
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  DBInterface dao = (DBInterface)context.getBean("JPA",JPAQueries.class);

  dao.retrieveRecords();
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main"  
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration 
problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [persistence.xml]

Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration 
problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace 
[http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence]

Offending resource: class path resource [persistence.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at pack.program.Program.main(Program.java:16)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence]

Offending resource: class path resource [persistence.xml]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255)
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt to use `persistence.xml` as a Spring config makes absolutely no sense, because `persistence.xml` is not a Spring config.

If you want to use JPA with Spring, you need to put `persistence.xml` into `META-INF` folder inside your source folder, and declare `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name = "persistenceUnitName" value = "MyJPA" />
</bean>
```

Then you can inject `EntityManager` into your Spring bean using `@PersistenceContext`:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

**See also:**

- [13.5 JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)

Comment: thanks axtavt, but if it's a regular java project which doesn't have META-INF folder, can i put the persistence.xml within the src folder?
and another question, how the bean that your write in example code will refer to the persistence file?

Comment: @eliorsh: You can simply create that folder inside your source folder and put `persistence.xml` there. `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` creates JPA `EntityManagerFactory` for persistence unit with the given name, and you define persistence units in `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be imported as follows:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
```

assuming the persistence.xml is present in META-INF directory which is a top-level directory in one of your jars on the classpath.

Comment: Vikdor thanks for your answer but the project isn't a JPA project is a java project because i need to use it as a server, so i don't have the META-INF folder and because of that i located the persistence file within the src folder

Comment: ok i converted the project into a JPA project and placed the persistence file within the META-INF folder.. and imported as you said, but i'm still getting the same exception

Comment: If it was not a JPA project, then you just need to make sure that the persistence.xml gets into your jar at some location and you would refer to that location with `classpath:` prefix. Now that you moved it into persistence.xml, can you list the contents of your jar and find the location of persistence.xml and update the path in the resource appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I Solved this..

What i did is to put the persistence.xml file within the META-INF folder
as vikdor and axtavt suggested. but in the application context i didn't import any file.. 
just wrote this

```
<bean id="JPA" class="pack.jpa.JPAQueries"/>
```

and its work!

Comment: Congratulations! You could accept axtavt answer, he was right.